# How do I make custom entity create new revision by default?

Tags: 8, entities

I made a custom entity that extends `RevisionableContentEntityBase`. I can use the web interface to create entities. If I edit an entity and check the box `Create new revision` then a new revision will be created. There is no configuration form available to set the default for `Create new revision`.

The custom entity is quite simple. It has a few base fields and was built using `drush generate module-content-entity`.

How do I make my custom entity create a new revision by default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally the default value is stored in bundle configurations. If you have no bundles then override [getNewRevisionDefault()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityForm.php/function/ContentEntityForm%3A%3AgetNewRevisionDefault/8.8.x) of your content entity form:

```
class MyEntityForm extends ContentEntityForm {

  protected function getNewRevisionDefault() {
    return TRUE;
  }

}
```

This class should already exist when you've generated the entity with Drush/Console. Check in the entity annotations that the class is used as form handler.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to 4k4's answer here, which is very good and specific, a coworker helped me arrive at another solution in overriding `ContentEntityForm::buildForm` function:

```
class MyEntityForm extends ContentEntityForm {

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['revision'] = [
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#default_value' => TRUE,
    ];
  }
}
```

The benefit of overriding the `buildForm` function is you can have a bit more form-specific logic, e.g. making it a hidden value or a checkbox.